# Print a message at the END of the log file

Tags: logging

I there a way to print messages to the log file so that they appear in the last few line of the log file?

Here is a MWE for my first attempt at doing this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\AtEndDocument{\typeout{*****************************************^^J
Here is my nice message^^J
*****************************************^^J}}
\begin{document}
Some important stuff.
\end{document}
```

At first sight this appears to do what I want because in this case the end of the logfile looks like:

```
...
***********************************************************************
Here is my nice message
***********************************************************************

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./MWE.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
7.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 20364 bytes).
Transcript written on MWE.log.
```

Unfortunately, this is deceptive because the guff between my message and the `Output written...` line is quite short here. In a real use-case the end of the log file looks more like:

```
...
*****************************************
Here is my nice message
*****************************************

[7] (./realexample.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2014/te
xmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/
enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-ec.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pub
lic/tex-gyre/qhvr.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ne
wtx/rntxmi.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/r
txb.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxmi.pf
b></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxr.pfb></usr
/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxsc.pfb></usr/local
/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/newtx/txex-bar.pfb></usr/local/texl
ive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/txex.pfb></usr/local/texlive/201
4/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/txsy.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/txsyb.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/public/txfonts/txsyc.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/
type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/
times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr
i8a.pfb>
Output written on realexample.pdf (7 pages, 124830 bytes).
SyncTeX written on realexample.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on realexample.log.
```

That is, in real-life there is a lot of space between my message and the end of the log file.

It turns out that Heiko Oberdiek has written the [atveryend](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) package that provides various commands like: `\AtVeryEndDocument`, `AtEndAfterFileList`, `\AtVeryVeryEnd`. Unfortunately, all of these commands give exactly the same output in the log file as using `\AtEndDocument`. Similarly, the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ettolbox) command `\AfterEndDocument` doesn't help either...

Does anyone know of a way to do this or if this is impossible? Given Heiko's package I suspect this can't be done.

Finally, perhaps I should say that the reason that I want to do this is to remind myself (and others) of the list of options to an undocumented in-house class...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have already found the latest possibilities for writing into the `.log` file:

- `\AtVeryVeryEnd` of package `atveryend`
- `\AfterEndDocument` of package `etoolbox`

Both hook into `\end{document}` to put the hook right before the final `\@@end`
(= the primitive `\end`). `\AtEndDocument` is too early, because the final `\clearpage` and reading of the `.aux` file with its rerun warnings are following.

But AFAIK there is no way inside TeX code to print something *after* the fonts, which are output by pdfTeX, when it finishes the output of the `.pdf` file.

A clumsy workaround would be to write the final message to a file, e.g. `\jobname.message` and to use a script, which first runs `pdflatex` and then appends the output of the file `\jobname.message` to the `.log` file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Heiko! I thought that was probably the case but hoped otherwise:)